# Error: failed linking file resources for setting custom font in Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments, custom-font

I am trying to apply custom font in android application by following

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml tutorial.

But I am getting **"failed linking file resources"** error. I have font `jameel_noori.ttf` in res>font folder and font resource file  `jameel.xml` having android  and app namespace. Please help me what am I doing wrong?

My app `minsdkversion` is 17. I have to use custom font in fragment.

This is my font resource file  `jameel.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- regular -->
<font
    android:font="@font/jameel_noori_regular"
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="400"

    app:font="@font/jameel_noori_regular"
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="400" />

<!-- italic -->
<font
    android:font="@font/jameel_noori_italic"
    android:fontStyle="italic"
    android:fontWeight="400"

    app:font="@font/jameel_noori_italic"
    app:fontStyle="italic"
    app:fontWeight="400" />

<!-- bold -->
<font
    android:font="@font/jameel_noori_bold"
    android:fontStyle="normal"
    android:fontWeight="700"

    app:font="@font/jameel_noori_bold"
    app:fontStyle="normal"
    app:fontWeight="700" />
```

Fragment layout file `fragment_single_dua.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical">


           <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_urdu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:text="@string/sample_arabic_text"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/jameel"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

This is error i am getting on build:

```
    C:\Users\Zoha\StudioProjects\SonayJagnayKayAzkaar1\app\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:6: error: attribute font (aka com.alhuda.duasapp.sonayjagnaykayazkaar:font) not found.
C:\Users\Zoha\StudioProjects\SonayJagnayKayAzkaar1\app\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:6: error: attribute fontStyle (aka com.alhuda.duasapp.sonayjagnaykayazkaar:fontStyle) not found.
C:\Users\Zoha\StudioProjects\SonayJagnayKayAzkaar1\app\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:6: error: attribute fontWeight (aka com.alhuda.duasapp.sonayjagnaykayazkaar:fontWeight) not found.
C:\Users\Zoha\StudioProjects\SonayJagnayKayAzkaar1\app\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:6: error: attribute android:font not found.
C:\Users\Zoha\StudioProjects\SonayJagnayKayAzkaar1\app\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:6: error: attribute android:fontStyle not found.
C:\Users\Zoha\StudioProjects\SonayJagnayKayAzkaar1\app\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:6: error: attribute android:fontWeight not found.
C:\Users\Zoha\StudioProjects\SonayJagnayKayAzkaar1\app\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:16: error: attribute font (aka com.alhuda.duasapp.sonayjagnaykayazkaar:font) not found.
C:\Users\Zoha\StudioProjects\SonayJagnayKayAzkaar1\app\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:16: error: attribute fontStyle (aka com.alhuda.duasapp.sonayjagnaykayazkaar:fontStyle) not found.
C:\Users\Zoha\StudioProjects\SonayJagnayKayAzkaar1\app\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:16: error: attribute fontWeight (aka com.alhuda.duasapp.sonayjagnaykayazkaar:fontWeight) not found.
C:\Users\Zoha\StudioProjects\SonayJagnayKayAzkaar1\app\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:16: error: attribute android:font not found.
C:\Users\Zoha\StudioProjects\SonayJagnayKayAzkaar1\app\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:16: error: attribute android:fontStyle not found.
C:\Users\Zoha\StudioProjects\SonayJagnayKayAzkaar1\app\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:16: error: attribute android:fontWeight not found.
C:\Users\Zoha\StudioProjects\SonayJagnayKayAzkaar1\app\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:26: error: attribute font (aka com.alhuda.duasapp.sonayjagnaykayazkaar:font) not found.
C:\Users\Zoha\StudioProjects\SonayJagnayKayAzkaar1\app\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:26: error: attribute fontStyle (aka com.alhuda.duasapp.sonayjagnaykayazkaar:fontStyle) not found.
C:\Users\Zoha\StudioProjects\SonayJagnayKayAzkaar1\app\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:26: error: attribute fontWeight (aka com.alhuda.duasapp.sonayjagnaykayazkaar:fontWeight) not found.
C:\Users\Zoha\StudioProjects\SonayJagnayKayAzkaar1\app\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:26: error: attribute android:font not found.
C:\Users\Zoha\StudioProjects\SonayJagnayKayAzkaar1\app\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:26: error: attribute android:fontStyle not found.
C:\Users\Zoha\StudioProjects\SonayJagnayKayAzkaar1\app\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:26: error: attribute android:fontWeight not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

I've tried both `android:fontFamily="@font/jameel"` and `app:fontFamily="@font/jameel"` in `Textview`, still error persists.

Comment: apply **XML** file in font family like `android:fontFamily="@font/jameel"` instead of applying **ttf** file  @Noor

Comment: Still nit resolved
\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:27: error: attribute android:font not found.

\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:27: error: attribute android:fontStyle not found.

\src\main\res\font\jameel.xml:27: error: attribute android:fontWeight not found.

error: failed linking file resources.

Comment: I tried what I told you to do and it worked perfectly on my machine. I don't know what you are doing so if you could send me your updated code with the changed error log I could help you.

Comment: @MittalVarsani Thank you so much for your help. I have edited the code and error log above. Please check. And can you please share your build.gradle configurations as well?

Comment: The error is resolved by adding  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2' in dependencies and changing compliesdkversion and targetsdkversion to 27.

Comment: But now facing this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53962249/android-custom-font-only-appears-in-layout-preview-not-on-real-device

Can you please help? Thank you